# Maternity Pay for postdoc on Professor's ESRC grant in the UK

Tags: postdocs, united-kingdom

How does maternity pay work if you are a postdoc on a professor's ESRC grant in the UK? Does it depend on the university policy, or is it defined by the ESRC? I understand generally how the university policies work, but for fixed-term contracts there is usually some clause stating "talk to your department manager," and as I am currently negotiating the job terms I was wondering if anyone had experience with maternity pay as a post-doc in this capacity.

Comment: If you are still negotiating the offer I would suggest asking this as part of that discussion.

Comment: Thanks yes, I of course plan to. However I was curious to understand what might be common/expected in these contexts as I am new to the UK, and therefor was hoping to hear from anyone with experience of pregnancy during an ESRC grant funded postdoc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was on maternity leave while being a postdoc on an EPSRC grant last year.

In short: when on an EPSRC grant, the EPSRC will effectively pay for your maternity leave (for the percentage of time that you are contracted on the grant).

Technically: your PI pays the maternity leave so that the grant will look overspent. Then when they submit the final claim, they claim for the statutory maternity leave. The relevant section of the UKRI* policy is ([source](https://committees.parliament.uk/writtenevidence/22286/default/)):

> RGC 8.3.1 At the end of the Grant Period We will reimburse costs
> incurred by You to cover any additional net parental leave costs that
> cannot be met within the announced grant cash limit including
> Statutory Maternity, Paternity and Adoption Pay for staff, within the
> Directly Incurred and Exceptions fund headings. This will be payable
> only for the percentage of time that the staff are contracted on the
> Grant

You can also check other UKRI documents, e.g. [here, RGC 8.3](https://www.ukri.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/UKRI-291020-guidance-to-fEC-grant-terms-and-conditions.pdf), or information on specific university pages, e.g. [here for UCL, UKRI section](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/research-innovation-services/research-services/managing-funding/parental-and-other-leave). Good luck!

*UKRI (AHRC, BBSRC, ESRC, EPSRC, MRC, NERC, STFC) = UK Research and Innovation

Comment: Thanks very much!  This is extremely helpful, and I really appreciate your sharing the experience.